# Sql query to transpose few of the rows to column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Job table

```
 Job id 
 Job title
 job type

JobID  jobTitle  jobType
1       design    manual
2       test      automated
3       deploy    automated
```

jobEmp table

```
 emp id
 job id
 first name
 last name
 job role(manager, lead, dev)

empid  jobid  firstname  lastname  jobrole
1       1       mickey    mouse      1
2       1       minnie    mouse      2
3       1       tom        jerry     3
4       2       minnie    mouse      1
5       2       abc                  3
```

so one job can have more than 1 emp, hence there will be more than 1 row for single job in jobEmp table.

I need to write a query with following output

```
jobId | jobTitle | jobType | manager      |   Lead       | dev
 1       Design     manual   mickey mouse   minnie mouse   tom jerry
 2       Test    Automated   minnie mouse   abc
```

Please help!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  What happens if there are more than 1 manager, lead, or dev on a project?

Comment: Meaningful (and consumable) sample data, and expected results will help us help you here. Transforming rows to columns, however, is known as pivoting, conditional aggregation, or a "cross tab".

Comment: I have added some sample data and expected result. I tried exploring pivot, but that always requires a aggregating function.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in the following way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (*) FROM
(SELECT
j.jobId,
j.jobTitle,
j.jobType,
CONCAT (je.first_name, je.last_name) AS NAME
FROM job j
INNER JOIN jobEmp as je) as JobTable

JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT jobRole AS 'manager' 
FROM jobEmp
WHERE 
role = 'manager'
 ) AS manager_col
 ON manager_col.jobId = JobTable.jobId 

JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT jobRole AS 'Lead' 
FROM jobEmp
WHERE 
role = 'lead'
 ) AS lead_col
 ON lead_col.jobId = JobTable.jobId 

JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT jobRole AS 'dev' 
FROM jobEmp
WHERE 
role = 'dev'
 ) AS dev_col

 ON dev.jobId = JobTable.jobId
```

Please make sure to change it based on the names of your tables because I guess there is no empty space between `Job id` for example